# window.getSelection "reselect"/"refresh"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try build toolbar for editable html elements. I have toolbar with "bold","italic" and others.

When user was selected any text and clicked "bold" I check does exists span and insert if not.

```
let hasWrap = (selectionObject.node==='SPAN');

if(!isBold){

  this.addClassToSelection('bold', !hasWrap, selectionObject);

}

addClassToSelection(className, wrapSpan = false, selectionObject = {}){

if(wrapSpan){
  let wrapper = document.createElement('SPAN');
  wrapper.className = className;
  wrapper.textContent = selectionObject.text;

  selectionObject.range.deleteContents();
  selectionObject.range.insertNode(wrapper);
}else{
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.anchorNode.parentNode.classList.add(className);
}
```

}

And it works. Also it works perfect if user will deselect text and select again.

But when user add bold (and js insert span element) and next click again "bold" to remove bold. System doesn't detect "span" element because still remember old `window.getSelection()`.

I've been tried use `window.getSelection()` directly without wrap in method
but still I see "p" or "div" as parent node. "span" is after select this text again.

How can I "reselect" this text to detect span but without user action.

What I'd like

1. user is selecting text
2. User is clicking "bold" button
3. system wrap text in span with bold class
4. user click "bold" button again and window.getSelection detect this span inserted in point 3

I use React in ES6 and I'd like use plain js without jQuery (wrap,unwrap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Make bold with Ctrl+b</div>
```

Would be much better to use `document.execCommand` - window.getSelection is much harder

HTML

```
<div contenteditable="true">Some Text</div>
```

JS - when custom event handling is required

```
document.execCommand('bold',false,true);
```

see the list of commands here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

and an "How To Use" here : http://codepen.io/netsi1964/full/QbLLGW/

Comment: Thanks. In code snippet ctrl/cmd+b doesn't work. 

dow document.exectCommand I can make bold all div, p. For me requires is selected text. And also don't user strong element only one span and many classes like underline, bold, italic to don't set manyy html elements.

This is no my idea but client. This is reason why I'd like work on window selection.

Comment: it works, thanks. In client requirements is span.bold instead b but maybe he will change it. It works good for all elements also for links.

Comment: Does it some good way to check what is "enabled" on selection? I mean information to add color for button bold, italic...


I can get parentNode.nodeName in loop or `document.queryselector('.some b')` but maybe exists better way

Comment: If anyone's reading in 2022, `execCommand` will be deprecated soon.